# Find tables which are being updat(ing)/(ed) with data most recently

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datatables

I am trying to test and demo business about Real-Time Reporting in Power BI (Pro Licence) connecting with DirectQuery mode to On-Premise MS SQL Server database.

Therefore, I am looking to pick on tables from SQL Server which are getting updated with data most recently.

Can anyone please help me with how to find which tables are updating so that I can pick on those tables for my Power BI Real-Time reporting demo?

I have tried to look up in this forum but don't see anything being asked for answered and have tried youtube but to no avail.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/09/sql-server-find-last-date-time-updated-for-any-table/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start from a Database Audit filtered to the UPDATE instruction.  You can then query the audit logs and sort by the most updated or most recently updated.

Start from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-action-groups-and-actions?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259&view=sql-server-ver15#database-level-audit-actions)

Answer (score 0):

Someone already posted this.

If a user wants to find out when was the last table updated he can query dynamic management view (DMV) – sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats and easily figure out when was the table updated last.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
 last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'AdventureWorks')
AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('test')
```

Running query provides accurate details of when was the table last updated in the AdventureWorks database.